# Running function on queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to manipulate my data from a queryset using `ListAPIView`. I wrote the query in plain Python first ([here][1]), but have been unable to get it working in Django.

I get a variety of errors, as I've tried using `get_queryset` too, but I'm doing something wrong. With the code below, I get `'TagList' should either include a queryset attribute`, or `override the get_queryset() method`. as an error

The below code tells me `global name 'instance' is not defined`.

```
class TagList(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = TagSortSerializer
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        json_data = instance.tag.all()
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `generics.RetrieveAPIView` rather than `generics.ListAPIView` because there is no `retrieve` method on the `generics.ListAPIView`. The following code should work:

```
class TagList(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = AllSerializer

    def retrieve(self, d):
        if d.tag.exists():
            ret = {}
            (level_one,) = [tagd for tagd in d.tag.all() if tagd.taglevel == 1]
            ret.update(level_one)
            ret.tag = [tagd for tagd in d.tag if tagd.taglevel != 1]
            newdata = [retrieve(d) for d in Task.objects.all()]
        else:
            print("no tag")
        return newdata()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only the `get_querset` function runs, so I am not getting the right results (I am just getting the result of `Task.objects.all()`). I put a traceback in side of `retrieve` and it does not get called

Comment: I just realized...shouldn't you inherit from `generics.RetrieveAPIView`? `generics.ListAPIView` only has a `list()` method. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrievemodelmixin

Comment: Please attempt an answer using that method then

Comment: Response there is `'Request' object has no attribute 'tag'`. Full trace: http://dpaste.com/0RC0A5H

Comment: the signature for `retrieve` is `retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`. Also, `retrieve` should only return one model instance, not a list.

Comment: How do I access the "intance"? I've updated my answer